# Reasons to use traditional next button over Infinite Scrolling

Tags: website-design, usability, interaction-design, user-behavior, users

To browse through the various pages ,
[Infinite Scrolling](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/) has been touted as a better alternative to the traditional next page icon because of a better user experience. It much easier to scroll down compared to pressing the next button.

Why does StackExchange which prides itself on user experience implement the traditional next page icons instead of Infinite Scrolling ??

What are the possible reason ??

Infinite Scrolling

[image]

Traditional next page button

[image]

Comment: @BennySkogberg: Paginating an article's content is not the same as paginating a list of articles...

Comment: There is a lot of subjective statements in this question. It's more of a rant than an actual question, I think. *"It much easier to scroll down compared to pressing the next button."* Is this true? Why do you say this? Even the linked article (which is barely more than spam for a wordpress plugin) includes the text 'Citation Needed' against points that it makes.

Comment: I wonder why this question has been marked as duplicate. This is not at all the same as the linked question which is about pagination while this one is about endless scrolling. Moderators should be a bit more sensitive for differences like this. Please reopen this question to have it receive a good answer!

Comment: @MikeLischke I agree with you

Comment: It agree it's not a duplicate of [Is there a point to paginating articles online?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/21375/is-there-a-point-to-paginating-articles-online). It is however a duplicate of [Regular pagination vs. infinite scroll](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/15982/regular-pagination-vs-infinite-scroll)

Answer (score 1):

> Why does StackExchange which prides itself on user experience
>   implement the traditional next page icons instead of Infinite
>   Scrolling ??

Possibly because, despite it's popularity, there is little evidence out there that infinite scrolling is a universal good thing.

I've personally never had it test better than multiple pages - either in user satisfaction or in tracking desired behaviours.

You might be interested in reading this [interesting story from Etsy where they tried infinite scrolling and went back to regular paged results](http://mcfunley.com/design-for-continuous-experimentation).

Comment: That Etsy presentation was fascinating. Seems like Infinite Scroll is one of those *'I have a solution, now to try to find a problem to attach it to'* situations rather than an *'identify what the problem is first'* route that should come first. And it also makes me want to go and work for Etsy!

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because infinite scrolling is not that well suited for web pages as it may create a huge page consuming a lot of resources. In an application you can optimize resource usage by not rendering any of the invisible parts (which is not possible in a webbrowser). Additionally, it somehow defeats the established kind of navigation used in Webbrowsers.

Google has an implementation for its image search which is kinda infinite scrolling (you have to click a button for more search results), but I find it suboptimal, as the page grows and grows and grows and it is sometimes difficult to not lose orientation.

Comment: Bing's Image Search is even worse, I often find myself disorientated while scrolling down, the page just "jumps" from one point to an other, and I have to scroll up to find the position where the recently loaded images begin.