# When to include "Previous" and "Next" button or link?

Tags: buttons, hyperlinks, next, previous

Happy new year guys.

I'm currently building a personal portfolio and I am thinking of including a "Next project", "Previous project" link where applicable to each individual project page. However, many portfolios I've come across only have a "Next Project" link but no "Previous Project" link. I think this, in a way, violates the symmetry principle. I also noticed for many websites there isn't even a "Next xxxxxx" link to begin with (like in e-commerce sites).

Can someone clarify when do we include a "Next xxxxxx", "Previous xxxxx" link to our page and why some people choose to only include "Next"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several reasons for the use or not of both buttons, many of them explained in different web pages easy to find with a simple Google Search ([Scrolling vs. pagination](https://crocoblock.com/blog/pagination-vs-infinite-scroll/)).

I describe the reasons that seem most obvious to me from a practical point of view.

---

The interface design previously defined by desktop use is currently totally influenced by use on mobile devices. In fact, many decisions are made from the user experience on smart phones and then adapted to the desktop version.

If moving from one project to the next involves a screen change, the back button conflicts with the browser button itself, making it totally unnecessary because it's redundant and because it takes up space on a small screen:

[image: Backs button]

If the change of projects is inside a carrousel, the `Next` or `Back` buttons are replaced by the slide forward `>` and backward `<` buttons.

As for the next button, the controversy is whether it is necessary, or is an infinite scrolling preferable as explained in [this answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/21375/115107).

All this depends on how the portfolio design is planned and depending on the number of projects to be shown. Returning to the topic of device use, the user is more familiar with finger scrolling to view all content prior to clicking a forward or back button at the bottom of the screen.

- If the content is long, the navigation buttons may not be seen
- If the navigation buttons are floating they can cover part of the content, being a portfolio it's inconvenient
- In some portfolios it's better to show all the projects is a *contact
  sheet* so the user clicks on the one they want to see in detail,
  usually shown in a modal window.
- If the projects are subdivided by subject, there may be a submenu for
  immediate accessibility.

There are many examples, visit [handsomefrank.com](https://www.handsomefrank.com/) which is a wide gallery of illustrators.

Comment: Hi @Danielillo, thank you for the detailed explanation :)
This makes a lot of sense. In my design, I think I'll go with only implementing the next project link. Thank you again for the helpful tips :)